# how to make dynamic order of <th> or <td> in <table> html?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Firstly, My English is so bad. SORRY ABOUT THAT!

I have a table like this:

```
 <table>
   <tr>
     <th> heading 1 </th>
     <th> heading 2 </th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td> data 2 </td>
     <td> data 2 </td>
   </tr>
```

But sometime i want it like this (order of td & th tags has changed):

```
 <table>
   <tr>
     <th> heading 2 </th>
     <th> heading 1 </th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td> data 2 </td>
     <td> data 1 </td>
   </tr>
```

How I can accomplish this?
Thank you!

Comment: @snwflk It like my question. But it is jquery and I don't familiar with JQUERY

Comment: @snwflk It suggest my idea. thanks you!

Comment: If this is in vuejs then you would be changing order of the data that renders those cells. Please provide a [mre]. I doubt you are working with raw html like thaat in vue

Comment: @charlietfl  I know that, but in current problem it more complex. Per <td don't like each other.

Comment: That's why you need a proper representation of the actual problem in the question. Changing the `<td>` position when they are rendered by vue is not the proper way to approach this but you haven't shown any vue code at all

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks you so much. This is first time I ask in a forum.

Comment: @charlietfl this is my resolve :V https://github.com/dinhdjj/account-shop--front/commit/ac4d65b62855f07b26988fbdfcc58174e1815726

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it with css `direction` tag. And then change the table class using javaScript DOM.

```js
var table = document.getElementById('table');
function changeDirection() {
  table.className = "table-ltr";
}
```

```css
.table-rtl {
  direction: rtl;
}

.table-ltr {
  direction: ltr;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="changeDirection()">Switch</button>

<table class="table-rtl" id="table">
   <tr>
     <th> heading 1 </th>
     <th> heading 2 </th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td> data 2 </td>
     <td> data 2 </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks you about your answer. But it not enough dynamic!

Comment: Your switch would be more useful if it went both ways using `classList.toggle()`

Comment: A|B|C => C|B|A It can but => B|A|C it can't. Thank yous. I have idea for this problem